# MongoDB: Filter multiple arrays in document and then return duplicate array into one data

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I have these sets of data on my DB:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "date": "2019/11/30",
  "title": "Data Title",
  "tags": ["Javascript", "NodeJS", "Big Data", "MongoDB"],
},{
  "id": 2,
  "date": "2019/10/30",
  "title": "Data Title 2",
  "tags": ["Javascript", "React", "NodeJS", "Postgres"],
}]
```

Currently what I want is to group the data by tags that returning the value of something like this:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "tags": "Javascript",
  "data": [{
    "date": "2019/11/30",
    "title": "Data Title",
   },{
     "date": "2019/10/30",
     "title": "Data Title 2",
   }],
   "count": 2
 }, {
   "id": 2,
   "tags": "React",
   "data": [{
     "date": "2019/10/30",
     "title": "Data Title 2",
   }],
   "count": 1
}]
```

**Question**: How do I get the data with mongodb aggregation query? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [**`$unwind`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726116/group-inner-array-values-without-unwind) the `tags` array and perform `$group` aggregation on it.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$tags" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$tags",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "title": "$title",
        "date": "$date"
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Hi Ashh, this is what I need for! Your answer truly useful for everyone reference. Thanks a lot!